# How to cancel api request using redux-observable and axios

Tags: reactjs, axios, redux-observable

I am using redux-observable and axios in my react project. I want to cancel api request when the same action is invoke. But my code below doesnt seem to cancel the request.

```
    const testEpic = action$ => action$.pipe(
  ofType('PUT_ACTION'),
  mergeMap(action => {
    return fromPromise(
      axios({
        url: 'apiUrl',
        data: {},
        method: 'put',
        headers : getHeaders().toObject(),
      })
    )
    .pipe(
      flatMap(response => ({
        data,
        type: 'PUT_ACTION_SUCCESS',
      })),
      takeUntil(action$.pipe(
        filter(action => action.type === 'PUT_ACTION')
      )),
      catchError(error => ({
        error: error.response,
        type: 'PUT_ACTION_ERROR'
      }))
    )
  })
)
```

Answer (score 1):

axios does not automatically cancel request. So, must write a CancelToken.
https://github.com/axios/axios#cancellation

```
const testEpic = action$ => action$.pipe(
  ofType('PUT_ACTION'),
  mergeMap(action => {
    const CancelToken = axios.CancelToken;   //cancelToken
    const source = CancelToken.source();     //cancelToken
    return fromPromise(
      axios({
        url: 'apiUrl',
        data: {},
        method: 'put',
        headers : getHeaders().toObject(),
        cancelToken: source.token            //this added
      })
    )
    .pipe(
      flatMap(response => ({
        data,
        type: 'PUT_ACTION_SUCCESS',
      })),
      takeUntil(action$.pipe(
        filter(action => action.type === 'PUT_ACTION’),
        tap(ev => source.cancel('canceled'))      //do cancel with message
      )),
      catchError(error => ({
        error: error.response,
        type: 'PUT_ACTION_ERROR'
      }))
    )
  })
)
```